# Test app with android system image

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have downloaded Android 4.4 ([KITKAT](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html)). There is an **android-19** system image in folder called **system-images** in android installed location in my pc.

I need to use this **Android 4.4** system image to test my app on the Android emulator.

How can I use this ? How can I create an **AVD** using this ?

Comment: I too stuck on same problem i created AVD But it's not launching

Comment: Me too. When i launched **AVD** it's displaying **ANDROID** and not go forward from there.

Comment: Yeah Exactly Same Problem For Me

Comment: @SoftwareSainath I found a solution. try it.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I am able to run **AVD** with **android-19**.

Previously I was edit the existing **AVD** and changed **Target** to `Android 4.4 - API Level 19`. It's not loaded the **AVD**.

Now I created a new **AVD** with **Target**  `Android 4.4 - API Level 19`. It takes a few minutes to display the android **kitkat** home screen. But it worked as charm.